# Get a list of dates indicating areas whose pixel cover is greater than 80%

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I am working with Black Marble [VNPA2](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_VIIRS_001_VNP46A2) nighttime light daily product. Before I export any image I check the pixel's quality and I remove any 'bad' pixels from the collection. But by removing the bad quality pixels, in many cases the area of interest, for a particular day, has very little coverage (most of the area is empty/nan values).

Using `Google Earth Engine`, how can I print the days, (starting from January 1st until the last day of December 2018) where the pixel coverage of my study area is equal or greater than 80%? By pixel coverage I mean, the remaining pixels after removing the bad quality ones.

[Here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6cfd15c19e008a7afb59796eb0535898) is the code for removing the bad quality pixels:

```
// Here I'm trying to set the Bits according to table 'Bitmask for QF_Cloud_Mask'
var mask_vnpa2_img = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QF_Cloud_Mask');
  var landWaterBackground = bitwiseExtract(qa, 1, 3)
  var cloudMaskQuality = bitwiseExtract(qa, 4, 5)
  var cloudDetectionResultsConfidenceIndicator = bitwiseExtract(qa, 6, 7)
  var shadowDetected = bitwiseExtract(qa, 8)
  var cirrusDetection = bitwiseExtract(qa, 9)
  var snowIceSurface = bitwiseExtract(qa, 10)

  var mask = ee.Image(1)
    .and(landWaterBackground.eq(1)) // Land no Desert
    .and(cloudMaskQuality.eq(3)) // High
    .and(cloudDetectionResultsConfidenceIndicator.eq(0)) // Confident Clear
    .and(shadowDetected.eq(0)) // No
    .and(cirrusDetection.eq(0)) // No cloud
    .and(snowIceSurface.eq(0)) // No Snow/Ice
    
  return image.updateMask(mask);
};

// Project the image to Mollweide.
var wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["World_Mollweide", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], \
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54009"]]';

var proj_mollweide = ee.Projection(wkt);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/001/VNP46A2')
  .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-01-02')
  .map(mask_vnpa2_img)
  .filterBounds(table)
  .select('DNB_BRDF_Corrected_NTL')
  .median()
  .clip(table)
  .reproject({
                crs: proj_mollweide,
                scale: 500
                  });

print(dataset)

// Bidirectional Reflectance Distribution Function (BRDF)
var brdf = dataset.select('DNB_BRDF_Corrected_NTL');
var brdfVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  palette: ['black', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red', 'white'],
};


function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}

Export.image.toDrive({
image: brdf,
description: 'ntl',
scale: 500, //100 for Band10
maxPixels: 1000000000000,
region: table,
folder: 'Landsat-5'
});
```

And the [shp](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/nikostziokas/tehran_54009) of my study area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are mixing methods from **ee.Image** objects and **ee.ImageCollection**. For this reason, I guess you probably considered the median determination for your dataset because your first approach didn't work. Several methods must be used in the **mask_vnpa2_img** function instead to be applied in dataset. It now looks as follows. Observe that I also added a concise file name in the return.

```
var mask_vnpa2_img = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QF_Cloud_Mask');
  var landWaterBackground = bitwiseExtract(qa, 1, 3)
  var cloudMaskQuality = bitwiseExtract(qa, 4, 5)
  var cloudDetectionResultsConfidenceIndicator = bitwiseExtract(qa, 6, 7)
  var shadowDetected = bitwiseExtract(qa, 8)
  var cirrusDetection = bitwiseExtract(qa, 9)
  var snowIceSurface = bitwiseExtract(qa, 10)

  var mask = ee.Image(1)
    .and(landWaterBackground.eq(1)) // Land no Desert
    .and(cloudMaskQuality.eq(3)) // High
    .and(cloudDetectionResultsConfidenceIndicator.eq(0)) // Confident Clear
    .and(shadowDetected.eq(0)) // No
    .and(cirrusDetection.eq(0)) // No cloud
    .and(snowIceSurface.eq(0)); // No Snow/Ice
  
  var date = image.get("system:time_start");
  
  return image.set('fileName', ee.String('image_').cat(ee.Date(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')))
              .reproject({crs: proj_mollweide, scale: 500})
              .clip(table)
              .updateMask(mask);

};
```

For trying out if my approach works, I considered all January month of 2018 (31 days) and an arbitrary area in USA. The **newImg** function computes the areas of each masked images and uses the criterion "equal or greater than 80%" of all area (corresponding to table polygon) for selecting and exporting only the desired images. This looks as follows:

```
var brdf_list = brdf.toList(brdf.size());

var total_area = ee.Image.pixelArea().reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: table,
    scale: 500,
    maxPixels: 1e13
    
  });

var newImg = brdf_list.map(function (img) {
  
  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea().mask(ee.Image(img).gte(0)).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: table,
    scale: 500,
    maxPixels: 1e13
    
  });
  
  var crit = ee.Number(area.get('area')).divide(total_area.get('area'));
  
  return ee.Algorithms.If(crit.gt(0.8), img, -1);
  
}).removeAll([-1]);

print(newImg);

newImg = ee.ImageCollection(newImg);

var first = newImg.first();

Map.addLayer(first, imageVisParam, 'brdf');

var exportImage = function(image, fileName) {
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image.first(),
    description: fileName,
    scale: 500, //100 for Band10
    maxPixels: 1000000000000,
    region: table,
    folder: 'Landsat-5'
  });
};

newImg.aggregate_array('fileName').evaluate(function (fileNames) {
  fileNames.forEach(function(fileName) {
    var image = brdf
      .filter(ee.Filter.eq('fileName', fileName));
    
    print(fileName);
    
    exportImage(image, fileName);

  });
});
```

After running the [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3605b5b09d61a635ecc1d293f73f99c7), at the GEE code editor, I got following result. Only 11 images (of 31 possibles) have an area of non masked pixels of 80 %; as it can be observed in Tasks tab to be uploaded to Google Drive. The image observed at the picture is the first one of the corresponding series.

[image]